# Android how to use single array list for all classes and activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist, overlay

In my app i am using googlemaps for that one main activity and for free hand sketch on googlemaps  for that one overlay class. For this free hand sketch to store paths one array list is used in overlay class. next for doing undo and redo functions in main activity so i have to use array list in main activity for that i am declare that array list in overlay class as public static. with the usage of static i got continuous drawing that's my problem.. how to use  array list with out using static in my app....

```
public class HandDrawOverlay extends Overlay {

   private boolean iseditMode = true;
   private boolean isTouched = false;
   private Paint paint = new Paint();
   private Point screenPt1 = new Point();
   private Point screenPt2 = new Point();
   public static ArrayList<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();    
   int x, y;
   GeoPoint geoP;
   HandDrawOverlay handDrawOverlay;
   private GoogleMapActivity mview = null;
   private boolean isUp = false;     

   public HandDrawOverlay(GoogleMapActivity mapviewdata){

      paint.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);
      paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
      paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      mview = mapviewdata;       
   }

   public static ArrayList<GeoPoint>  getBitmap(){
          return points;
   }   

   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {    
    if (points != null && points.size() > 1) {           
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(points.get(0), screenPt1);

        for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {            
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(points.get(i), screenPt2);
            canvas.drawLine(screenPt1.x, screenPt1.y, screenPt2.x, screenPt2.y, paint);
            screenPt1.set(screenPt2.x, screenPt2.y);                 
        }
     }
  }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
    if(mview.isEditMode() && (iseditMode)){         

        x = (int) e.getX();
        y = (int) e.getY();           
        geoP = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);    
        Log.i("", "geoP" +geoP);

        switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                            
            isTouched = true;        
            points.add(geoP);                               
            break;              

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:            
            if (isTouched = true)
                points.add(geoP);               
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:          
            if (isTouched = true)
                points.add(geoP);                    
            isUp = true;
            handDrawOverlay = new HandDrawOverlay(mview);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(handDrawOverlay);
            break;
        }           
        mapView.postInvalidate();    
        return true;            
      }      
       return false;
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use this.

```
public class Hiroshima {

    private static Hiroshima hr = new Hiroshima();


    public ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<String>();


      private Hiroshima(){}

      public static Hiroshima getInstance(){

          return hr;
      }

}
```

Now you can use this ArrayList from Anywhere.And It will give you same intance.

In your Activity write down as below.

```
Hiroshima hx = Hiroshima.getInstance();
```

Comment: hx is reference of that class . To use ArrayList you have to write hx.mImages .

Comment: ur's code is working ... but we got same problem of getting continuous drawing.... as like that when array list  used as static in previous i am using...